# adding space in strcat

Tags: c, string, strcat

I have two strings `char str1[41]`  e `char str2[41]`. If I use `strcat` function to concatenate them I get an unique string without space instead I would have space between these.

this could be a way:

```
strcat(strcat(str1, " "),str2)
```

Does it exist another way?

Answer (score 8):

`sprintf(destination, "%s %s", str1, str2);`

You'll have to provide a destination. You could use `str1` as your destination and it *might* work correctly, but note the way you're currently doing things could cause you to overrun `str1`s buffer.

`asprintf()` will allocate a buffer for you, of the correct (read: safe) length, but you must remember to `free()` that buffer when you're done with it.

Comment: `asprintf()` is great but be aware that it's not POSIX standard and thus not available everywhere

Comment: http://www.mibsoftware.com/libmibx/parse/asprintf.c appears to be a liberally licensed version of it in source form. I've not used that implementation myself.

Answer (score 2):

If strcat is a requirement, I believe that the most efficient way would be:

```
size_t length = strlen(str1);
str1[length] = ' '; // overwrite null termination
str1[length+1] = '\0'; // add a new null termination
strcat(str1, str2);
```

And of course, be aware of buffer overflows.

Comment: even more efficient (if `strcat()` isn't required): `strcpy( str1+length+1, str2 )` instead of `str1[length+1] = '\0'` and `strcat(str1, str2);`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Yes, added clarification. If strcat isn't required, then `memcpy(str1+strlen(str1), str2, strlen(str2)+1);` would be far more efficient.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think memcpy would be more efficient because of the need to determine strlen(str2). That would cause you to walk through that string twice, while a simple strcat walks through it only once, stopping at the NULL.

Comment: @mah strcat will both check each character for null and copy it, so it executes roughly twice the amount of instructions as memcpy. In theory, memcpy+strlen together should be pretty much the same amount of instructions as strcat. I suppose it isn't obvious which would be the fastest, it depends on how heavily memcpy is optmized, cache memory etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Placing curly brackets around the space solves the problem:
`strcat(str, {' '})`

Answer (score 0):

Add a whitespace at the end of **str1** before concatenation with **str2** , or add a whitespace at the beginning of **str2** and then concatenate the two strings...

Comment: the first thing is exactly what is done by `strcat(strcat(str1, " "),str2)`

Answer (score 0):

To maintain efficiency and respect the limited array size of `str1`,

```
size_t Len1 = strlen(str1);
size_t Len2 = strlen(str2);
if ((Len1 + 1 + Len2) >= sizeof(str1)) {
  ; // handle error
}
str1[Len1] = ' ';
memcpy(&Str1[Len1+1], str2, Len2 + 1);
```

**OR**

as defined in C11 K.3.7.1.3., if available, use `strcpy_s()`

```
size_t Len = strlen(str1);
strcpy_s(&str1[Len], Len - sizeof(str1), " ") || strcpy_s(&str1[Len+1], Len - (sizeof(str1) + 1), str2);
```

---

Premise: `strcat()` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope it will help you.

```
strcat(string1, " ");
strcat(string1, string2);
```